# Calculating $(5(\cos(20^{\circ})+i\sin(20^{\circ})))^3$ is equal to both a complex number and real number?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, real-numbers

Recently, I was presented with the problem $(5(\cos(20^{\circ})+i\sin(20^{\circ})))^3$.

To solve it, I know that for a complex number $z=r(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$ then for $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, $z^n=r^n(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))=r^n\operatorname{cis}(n\theta)$, so I distribute the power and get $(5(\cos(20^{\circ})+i\sin(20^{\circ})))^3=125\operatorname{cis}(60^{\circ})$. This is a simple problem and I get a reasonable answer of $\frac{125}{2}+\frac{125i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

However, when I plug this expression into Wolfram Alpha, it surprisingly not only gives the answer I have gotten, but also a real number, as shown below. [image]

The result I got and the second and third outputs of Wolfram Alpha clearly are not real numbers, as they doesn't even lie on the real axis,

[image]

---

My question is, what is going on here? I see no way to convert it into a real number. Am I fundamentally missing something important that can convert an imaginary number into a completely real one? Or is Wolfram Alpha high or something.

Comment: What exactly did you plug into Worlfram|Alpha?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I used Wolfram Alpha to evaluate both sine and cosine of 20 and substituted it into the original equation. 

www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+%285%28%28-1%2F2+%28-1%29%5E%288%2F9%29+%281+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%282%2F9%29%29%29%2Bi*%28-1%2F2+%28-1%29%5E%287%2F18%29+%28-1+%2B+%28-1%29%5E%282%2F9%29%29%29%29%29%5E3

Comment: If you provide Wolfram Alpha with the expression that appears in your post (translated to radians) it appears to [work](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%285%28cos%28pi%2F9%29%2Bisin%28pi%2F9%29%29%29%5E3).

Comment: I guess the question ought to be: Why does "simplify (5((-1/2 (-1)^(8/9) (1 + (-1)^(2/9)))+i*(-1/2 (-1)^(7/18) (-1 + (-1)^(2/9)))))^3" break Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: Wolfy sometimes does weird things.

Comment: I see.  You entered the terms $(-1)^{q}; q\in \mathbb Q$.  Wolfram takes those as multivalued expressions.  As there are nine possibly ways to interpret $(-1)^{\frac 29}$ wolfram listed answers for each evaluation.  .... Instead of putting in $(-1)^{q}$ you should put in $e^{2\pi\cdot qi}$.  That has only one evaluation for $q=\frac 29$ and you should only get one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you entered has things like $(-1)^{1/9}$ in it. That's a negative number raised to a non-integer power. Such things have ambiguous meaning, and WA is just moving forward with all the interpretations of that.

Like $(-1)^{1/9}$ can mean the real number $\sqrt[9]{-1}$, which is $-1$. Or it can mean the principal complex 9th root of $-1$, which is $\exp(2\pi i/9)$. Or it could stand for the collection of all nine complex roots of $-1$.

Later you only get three results (instead of 9) because the expression also includes cubing, and some of the final results coincide.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all notice that $\mathbb{R}⊆\mathbb{C}$. Secondly, we have:

$$\left(5\left(\cos\left(20^\circ\right)+i\cos\left(20^\circ\right)\right)\right)^3=$$
$$\left(5\left(\exp\left(20^\circ i\right)\right)\right)^3=5^3\exp\left(3\cdot20^\circ i\right)=125\exp\left(60^\circ i\right)\tag1$$

Now, note that $\cos60^\circ=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sin60^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Comment: $\mathbb R \not \in\mathbb C$.   $\mathbb R \subseteq \mathbb C$.

Comment: @fleablood true, I am sorry.